# Equipotential Lines

Tags: electrostatics, potential, voltage

In 2D why exactly do lines of equal potential exist on a point charge at rest? This doesn't make sense to me if the point charge is hypothetically a lone charge undisturbed by other charges.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what you're asking? Typically we say you can't define the potential at the actual location of a point charge, so we wouldn't draw any equipotential line through the point charge.

Comment: All the concepts in electrostatics are based on the idea of "test charges" which are so small that they don't substantially disturb the charge distribution that we are measuring. This is merely a generalization of the approximation that position, momentum etc. measurements in classical mechanics don't disturb the classical system, either. It stays valid, right until we hit quantum mechanics and then it falls apart completely. Of course the very idea of a resting charge (or a resting anything) falls apart completely in QM.

Answer (score 0):

In 3 dimensions, equipotential surfaces are a family of surfaces such that Electrostatic Potential $\phi$ is $\textbf{constant}$ along them. A direct consequence of the fact that $\vec{E}=-\nabla\phi$ is, using this result from Vector Calculus, that the electric field $\vec{E}$ points in some direction $\textbf{normal}$ (or perpendicular) to surfaces $\phi=constant$, i.e., equipotential surfaces. This way, in the case of a point charge, the electric field produced is radial according to Coulomb's Law, so the equipotential surfaces are spherical shells centered at the position of the charge. A physical consequence of the existence of equipotential surfaces is that the Work exerted upon a charge immersed in some  electric field is zero along some path contained in those surfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Equipotential lines are a representation of constant electric potential. Electric potential is given by V = kq/r. So if there was a point charge, then at some fixed distance away from it (r), electric potential will exist.

The reason the equipotential lines for a point charge are propagating circles is that 'r' is the same value at some circle around the point charge, so there will be constant electric potential around the point charge.

Comment: If that's the case, there is a potentially infinite number of equipotential lines, correct?

Comment: Yes , you can draw as many equipotential lines as you want, since there is one through any point of the plain except trough the point charge itself. But this is not meaningful , on a map you can draw as many lines of equal hight but do you want to?